# Filtering Dataframe inside a loop does not produce the correct result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Filtering the dataframe using a loop for the filter value extraction gives an empty dataframe.

When i try to filter my dataframe:

```
code = 46897
print(len(df[df["ProductCode"]==code]))
```

I get the correct number of rows, 52.

But, when i try filtering using a loop:

```
for el in range(0, 1):
    code = df_products["ProductCode"][el]
    print(code)
    # 46897 printed
    print(len(df[df["ProductCode"]==code]))
```

I get 0.

Comment: Seems in column are integers, can you try `print(len(df[df["ProductCode"]==int(code)]))` ?

Comment: Use `\`\`\`` to format multi-line code blocks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by labels in index and column `ProductCode` and then convert value to integer, because `code` is string in your data:

```
for el in range(0, 1):
    code = df_products.loc[el, "ProductCode"]
    print(code)

    print(len(df[df["ProductCode"]==int(code)]))

    #alternative
    print((df["ProductCode"]==int(code)).sum())
```